# How to click on div class element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to click on a div element that has a custom ID (in this example 12257237).

Here is the element :

```
<div class="product-params-oem__title product-params-oem-title-js ga-click" data-article-id="12257237" data-gac="OEM_info" data-ga-action="detail">
  <span>Afficher les numéros OEM du produit</span>
</div>
```

I have tried this but without success:

```
python_button = driver.find_element_by_id("12257237") 
python_button.click() #click fhsu link
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`12257237` is not `id` attribute, it's `data-article-id` attribute. Those are two different things. You can use `css_selector`

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-article-id="12257237"]')
```

Or `xpath`

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-article-id="12257237"]')
```